# Translating Views Pager

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n, paging

Help, how to translate paginator in views? In my views I used a mini pager with tags backwards/forwards. Tried to do through translate interface, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Installing [i18nviews](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) Module, You should check *admin/config/regional/translate/translate* where you should search for the string

Here is a discussion going about it : [Views pager translation not working](https://www.drupal.org/node/2112281#comment-7971057)

[image]

Comment: I've tried so does not work!

Comment: Try the patch I mentioned in my answer.. Let me know if it works